# Ubuntu slows and freezes whenever the memory

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, ram, swap

Ever since upgrading to Ubuntu 18 from 16 on my machine (2GB RAM) I am experiencing slowdowns of the system and freezes of the current program (Chrome, for example) whenever the physical RAM memory is maxed out and Ubuntu starts using swap.

I downgraded and installed Ubuntu 16 but the problem persisted.

I can hear the HHD 'grinding' when the problem happens. And so I created a swap partition on a USB disk on key, which I set to higher priority than the swap on the HHD. The problem persists.

I wanted to ask for guidance in diagnosing or fixing the problem.

P.S. there is 27GB of free space. SMART parameters AFAICT don't indicate a problem (except for 'old age')

Comment: you can try switching to lighter desktop environment like XUbuntu or LUbuntu

Comment: Try some different settings for `swappiness`, see: [What is swappiness and how do I change it?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#What_is_swappiness_and_how_do_I_change_it.3F)

Answer (score 2):

With 2GB of RAM this is hardly surprising. You may want to switch to a lighter desktop environment, such as xfce. To install xfce, execute

```
sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop
```

Log out, select XFCE DE, and log in again. This will give you some more headroom memory wise.

Note that any modern browser is a memory hog. At the machine I'm using currently, Chrome consumes approx 2GiB memory with 6 open tabs. Getting more memory is the *real* cure for your problem, as 2GiB is simply not enough for multitasking with a modern OS and modern applications. A suggested minimum is 4GiB.

Comment: I installed Xubuntu as you suggested and instantly got 290 MB! Thank you. Will order more memory.

Answer (score 1):

The "grinding" noise from the HDD indicates you've got a bad HDD. It's trying to re-calibrate.

You also don't have enough RAM.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is...as you have noticed SWAP ;)

SWAP is a "file" on your HDD that is used as RAM (when physical RAM is over). Since HDDs are REALLLYYY slow (comparing to RAM) this is why you are experiencing Your problems.

**Advises:**

- add more RAM
- don't use so many application at once ;)
- disable SWAP
- disable background services
- monitor memory usage `top` `htop` `free` (those are console programs) or Ubuntu `System Monitor`

How to enable/disable SWAP:

```
sudo swapoff -a # turns it OFF
sudo swapon -a  # turns it ON again
```

How to install `htop`:

```
 sudo apt-get install htop
```

Comment: With 2G RAM, you certainly don't want to disable swap. Depending on how big swap is set for now, you may even want to increase it. But... this isn't a swap problem anyway... it's a bad HDD.

Comment: Disabling swap has made browser tabs crash for me when there is not enough memory, with no slowdown whatsoever. All in all- slightly better than freezing to a halt.

Comment: (I may have messed around with other settings as well to get to this result, like installing Early OOM, and messing with swapiness settings.) @heynnema may very well be true, I'll order some other drive (SSD) and report back.

Comment: @amba2 please describe the Early OOM and vm.swappiness things that you did. You should probably undo these and just add more RAM. 2G isn't enough. Make sure that you end up with pairs of equal spec RAM sticks so you can get the speed advantage of "memory interleaving".

Comment: @heynnema I installed Early OOM by following the instructions from https://github.com/rfjakob/earlyoom#download-and-compile :
git clone https://github.com/rfjakob/earlyoom.git ->
cd earlyoom -> 
make -> 
sudo make install

About the Swappiness, after creating a 2GB SWAP partition on a pen drive with GParted, I set the priority of the created SWAP partition to be higher than the system SWAP partition by adding the following line to /etc/fstab:
UUID=807435c0-6da1-4c25-b13d-c199a7f15135 none swap sw,pri=5 0 0

Comment: @amba2 oh no. Please remove Early OOM, and ESPECIALLY remove swap from the pen drive! Remember to undo your /etc/fstab changes. Just buy some more RAM, and let the system work as it should. Change vm.swappiness if you wish... if you know how it works. As I mention in my answer... replace the bad HDD and add more RAM :-)

Comment: I'll just buy a new machine. Right now I can have 3 Chrome tabs open before Ubuntu goes crazy with either disk thrashing and freezes or killing one of the tabs (if swapoff is evoked). This means that if I double the memory to 4GB, I could have about 7 tabs open. I used to have over a hundred tabs open on a 2GB windows machine.

Comment: @heynnema I did some searching before posting, and my problem is very prevalent. If there were a problem with the HDD, why doesn't it show on SMART parameters? I should add that I don't seem to have any problem otherwise writing to or reading from the disk.

Comment: @amba2 Lots of folks have RAM/swap issues. You're not the only one. Because of the "grinding" noise your HDD makes, I indicated a bad HDD. SMART probably wouldn't show recalibrations. A pen drive for swap is nuts. You've been fighting with a low memory condition for quite some time. You can't compare an old Windows XP w/2G RAM to a full Ubuntu installation. Chrome is a memory hog. Use something else. Bite the bullet and add RAM for a total of 8G minimum. Buy 2x4G sticks so that you can take advantage of memory interleaving.

Comment: @amba2 also... with a HDD making grinding noises, and only 27G free space, you're due for a HDD upgrade too.

Comment: I connected the HDD externally to a Windows machine with a SATA-> USB cable. I checked the drive with Acronis Drive Monitor, which shows it has 100% life left. I can access all files (with Ext2Fsd Volume Manager). So a bad HDD is pretty much ruled out AFAIAC.

I did end up upgrading RAM to the 4GB max, but shortly after Ubuntu stopped booting altogether, and I bought a new laptop, so I did not get a chance to see how it may have improved performance.